# Toxi-style tag query broken after adding join operation

Tags: sql, join, group-by, mariadb

I'm trying to select items from a toxi-style database. The database has the following structure:

Table "**SONGS**":

| index | title | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 'a001' | 'title1' | ... |
| 'a002' | 'title2' | ... |

Table "**TAGMAP**":

| index | item_index | tag_index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 'a001' | 't001' |
| 2 | 'a001' | 't003' |
| 3 | 'a001' | 't004' |
| 4 | 'a002' | 't003' |
| 5 | 'a002' | 't005' |

Table "**TAGS**":

| tag_index | name |
| --- | --- |
| 't001' | 'foo' |
| 't002' | 'bar' |
| 't003' | 'foobar' |

I want to have a query, that will select items with ALL desired tags present. Using [this article](http://howto.philippkeller.com/2005/04/24/Tags-Database-schemas/), I've built the following query, that works:

```
SELECT s.title, s.description
FROM (songs s, tagmap tm)
WHERE (tm.tag_index IN (7,3))
AND s.index = tm.item_index
GROUP BY s.item_index 
HAVING COUNT(s.item_index) = 2 
ORDER BY s.date DESC
```

The `IN (7,3)` array is dynamically populated in practice, with `COUNT(...) = <x>` being the length of the desired tags array. This query works.

However, now I also need the names of all associated tags returned with every item. Previously (a query of all items, without respecting any tags), this worked by using joins. But now, when introducing the same `JOIN` I used previously to this query, it falls apart. The result isn't the same, it's less items and they are even completely different!

If tag2 and tag2 are the tags I'm interested in, the expected output would be:

| Title | Description | ... | tags |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| title1 | something | ... | tag1, tag2, tag3 ... |
| title2 | otherthing | ... | tag2, tag3, tag5 ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

The following record would not be included because one of the required tags (in the specific case, "*tag3*") is missing:

( 'title5'   , 'somewhere'   , ... , 'tag1, tag2, tag5 ...' )

Here's my attempt at this task:

```
SELECT s.title, s.description, GROUP_CONCAT(t2.name SEPARATOR ', ') as tags
FROM (songs s, tagmap tm)
LEFT JOIN tagmap tm2 ON s.index = tm2.item_index 
LEFT JOIN tags t2 ON tm2.tag_index = t2.tag_index
WHERE (tm.tag_index IN (7,3))
AND s.index = tm.item_index
GROUP BY s.item_index 
HAVING COUNT(s.item_index)=2 
ORDER BY s.date DESC
```

I fail to see where this is broken so any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Can you update your post with the expected output?

Comment: @lemon , I have edited the question. I hope this is understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the filtering and use conditional aggregation to check if your tags are present among all the tags.

```
SELECT s.title, s.description, GROUP_CONCAT(t.tag_name) AS tags
FROM      songs s
LEFT JOIN tagmap tm
       ON s.index = tm.item_index
LEFT JOIN tags t 
       ON tm.tag_index = t.tag_index
GROUP BY s.title, s.description
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN t.tag_index IN (2,3) THEN 1 END) = 2
```

Note that this solution assumes you don't have duplicated tags. If you can have a title associated multiple times to a single tag, you should split the conditions in the `HAVING` clause as follows:

```
HAVING MAX(tag_index=2) = 1 
   AND MAX(tag_index=3) = 1
```

This ensures that there's at least one true value (the respective tag exists).

Comment: This feels very elegant and solid, thank you very much. I will try to examine the CASE WHEN part, this is surely something I need to learn. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to for a second bridge table,.

also don't mix comma separated join with other joins, as comma separated are old style anyway

so
basically

```
SELECT MAX(s.title) as tiltle, MAX(s.description) as description, GROUP_CONCAT(t2.name SEPARATOR ', ') as tags
FROM songs s  INNER JOIN tagmap tm ON s.index = tm.item_index
INNER JOIN   tags t2 ON tm.tag_index = t2.tag_index
WHERE (tm.tag_index IN (7,3))
GROUP BY s.item_index 
HAVING COUNT(s.item_index)=2 
ORDER BY s.date DESC
```

to get all the tags you need to get all item.index that have those tags

```
SELECT MAX(s.title) as tiltle
 #, MAX(s.description) as description
  , GROUP_CONCAT(t2.name SEPARATOR ', ') as tags
FROM SONGS s  INNER JOIN TAGMAP tm ON s.index = tm.item_index
INNER JOIN   TAGS t2 ON tm.tag_index = t2.tag_index
WHERE s.index IN ( SELECT item_index FROM TAGMAP WHERE tag_index IN ('t003','t004'))
GROUP BY s.index 
HAVING COUNT(tm.item_index)=3 
#ORDER BY s.date DESC
```

| tiltle | tags |
| --- | --- |
| title1 | foo, foobar, foobar3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UrGdOS4m)

If both have to be at the same time tag for the item you can do following

```
SELECT MAX(s.title) as tiltle
 #, MAX(s.description) as description
  , GROUP_CONCAT(t2.name SEPARATOR ', ') as tags
  
FROM SONGS s  INNER JOIN TAGMAP tm ON s.index = tm.item_index
INNER JOIN   TAGS t2 ON tm.tag_index = t2.tag_index
GROUP BY s.index 
having SUM( (tm.tag_index = 't003') + (tm.tag_index = 't004'))  = 2
#ORDER BY s.date DESC
```

| tiltle | tags |
| --- | --- |
| title1 | foo, foobar, foobar3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/km63ykh9)

Comment: This only returns the tags I searched by in the `t.names as tags`, not all tags the item has. How could I include all of the items tags in the result?

Comment: i adjusted the query, to get all tags

Comment: Thank you. I see the edit you made and I think I understand. However, using the `HAVING COUNT(x)=y`, I only get `y` tags listed in the `GROUP_CONCAT`. I can't set this to "however many tags each item has", because items have differing numbers of tags. Completely omitting the `HAVING COUNT` will not help, because then I'd get results of basically "item has some of the selected tags" as opposed to "item has all the selected tags". 
I need my results to have ALL selected tags while including `ALL tags the item has` (however many that may be) in the result.

Comment: yes hat is what the having wi do, if you want to count the tags and have a certain number, you would choose > 1 or >3, with = you will only get items that have that number

Comment: Let's say an item has 5 different tags. If I'm querying for 2 tags and set `COUNT >= 2`, I'll also get items with just **some** of the tags, but not all of them. That's the whole problem. I get the results I need, but I'm struggling with getting all of the item's tags in the result.

Comment: then you need a having but different from what you have see changes

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have learned quite a few things from your continuous edits. However, I will accept the other answer, because I think it will be the more straight-forward answer for people coming across this post via Google. Thanks again, have a nice day!

Comment: as it really doesn't doesn't differ from ...